# Cocoa - explanation of view handling

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

I'm learning Cocoa at the moment, and have followed 'generic' tutorials on getting a basic form with a button and label.

With the `.xib`, I've added an 'Object' (instance of `NSObject` subclass), and have also created a `ViewController` class, which I connect to my view by setting `Custom Class` to ViewController. I then code up my `ViewController.h` and `.m` files adding a `pressedButton` method, and a label (myLabel). This all works OK (ie. the label updates when the button is pressed).

My question is: what am I actually doing with this process in C++ terms (a language I'm more familiar with)? As I understood it, my 'Object' (set to class ViewController) represents an instance of the .xib file (may be wrong here), and with this set to the ViewController class, I'm able to make outlets and actions in ViewController.h/.m, but I'm still not sure what's really going on behind the scenes.

Lastly, the `XCode` template provides an `AppDelegate` class 'free'. Given I'm managing my controls via my `ViewController` class, what would this file/object be used for - is it for application specific things that do not relate to the view itself, or is it also used to manage the controls on the form too (like you see in some tutorials I think)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope, I understood the first part of your question well. The .xib (xml verison of nib file) does not represent a class or object. It is rather used to create a view object with all its subviews (each an object) and link it properly to your view controller.

It is most common and automatically generated that way, that the underlying view within your nib file corersponds to self.view (from your view controller's point of view).
You could access each view created by the nib file by navigating though the subview hierarchy of self.view. Alternatively you could define tags within nib/IB (Interface builder) to access individual view objects more easily.

"Just for your convenience" the IBOutlets were introduced. You can define an IBOutlet in the interface of your view controller and link it using IB to the dedicated object that is created using the xib file. 
I am saying "Just for your covenience" because it is not really neccessary, considering other ways of addressing your view objects. But it is more than convenient and therfore strongly recommended and stimply the standard way of doing it.

You could even add further views programmatically to a form/view that was created using IB. You can change properties of those views programmatically.

The view and the subvies are created in that very moment when your view controller is initialized with a nib file using the `initWithNibName:bundle:` method. Then the nib file (xib these days) is opened, its content is parsed and interpreted and all views are created and added to their superviews respectively and their properties and action: selectors etc. are set accordingly. Again, the whole process is designed for your convenience. You could even create all the views etc. programmatically - witout any nib file at all. The `loadView` method of your custom view controller would be the appropriate place of dong so.

Second question: 
AppDelegate is designed for application wide actions etc. If you can manage everything fine within your view controllers then you would not need to change anything on the AppDelegate. 
It is often used as a container for variables or functions of global character (which are then properties and members of the app delegate object). Sometimes you may see it neccessary to override some of the AppDelegates methods like application:didFinishLanuncing or applicationDidBecomeActive.
Strictly spoken, UIApplicationDelegate is no class that you subclass. It is a protocol that you implement. (Very much like interfaces within Java - sort of overcoming the lack of multiple inheritance that you are familiar with from C++).

Comment: Thanks so much Hermmann...very well explained. I know I have to stop thinking in C++ with Objective-C, but it does help to see the parallels.